# An identity with $f'(x)$ and the integral of $f$

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $(-1,\infty)$,and satisfies
$$f'(x)+f(x)-\frac{1}{x+1}\int_0^x f(t)dt =0,$$
and $f(0)=1$. Show that for $x\geq 0$, we have $$e^{-x}\leq f(x)\leq 1.$$

It is easy to conclude that $f(x)\geq e^{-x}$ by contradiction argument. While I find it is quite difficult to prove $f\leq 1$.

My project is as follows. 
$$f'(x)-\frac{1}{x+1}\int_0^x f(t)dt =-f(x)\leq -e^{-x},$$
integrating yields
$$f(x)-f(0)-\int_0^x \frac{1}{t+1}\int_0^t f(s)dsdt\leq e^{-x}-1$$
$$f(x)\leq e^{-x}+\int_0^x f(s)[\ln (x+1)-\ln(s+1)]ds.$$
If I apply the gonwall inequality:
$$0<f(x)\leq g(x)+\int_0^x h(t)f(t)dt\Rightarrow f(x)\leq g(x)+\int_0^x h(s)g(s)e^{\int_s^x h(t)dt}ds$$
I get some messy quantities.